# The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(ShoppingList, int, Cursor, SQLiteDatabase, ListView) is undefined

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

When I use a SimpleCursorAdapter, Eclipse says The constructor SimpleCursorAdapter(**ShoppingList, int, Cursor, SQLiteDatabase, ListView**) is undefined.

Here is my .java:

```
package com.shoppinglist;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;

public class ShoppingList extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        SQLiteDatabase db;
        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Items.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
        db.setVersion(1);
        db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
        db.setLockingEnabled(true);

        final String CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS = 
            "CREATE TABLE tbl_items ("
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "item_name TEXT);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS);

        Cursor c = db.query(CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        startManagingCursor(c);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.rowlayout, c, db, listview);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

        Button button1main = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
        button1main.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)  {
            final Dialog additem = new Dialog(ShoppingList.this);
            additem.setContentView(R.layout.maindialog);
            final EditText et = (EditText)additem.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
            additem.setTitle("Type your item");
            additem.setCancelable(true);
            et.setHint("Type the name of an item...");

            Button button = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)  {
                    additem.dismiss();
                }
            });
            additem.show();

            Button ok = (Button) additem.findViewById(R.id.ok);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    final String text = et.getText().toString();
                    additem.dismiss();
                    et.setText("");
                }
            });
       }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not used a `SimpleCursorAdapter` before, but the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) states that the constructor is:

```
public SimpleCursorAdapter (Context context, 
        int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to)
```

however your call to the constructor passes in an `SQLiteDatabase` in place of the `String` array:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            R.layout.rowlayout, c, db, listview);
```

Comment: What would be an example of what to put for the from string and the to int?

Comment: @Cg2916 read the [notepad tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex1.html) which has an example

Comment: Ok. But now I get a nullpointerexception here: `Cursor c = (Cursor) db.selectAll();` I define my db like this: `final DataHelper db = null;`

Comment: You set `db` to be `null`, then attempt to call a method on it: `db.selectAll()`, which will always throw a `NullPointerException`.  You even have a `@SuppressWarnings("null")` as the IDE is trying to tell you that it will be a problem.  You need to create an instance of `DataHelper`.  See step 8 of the tutorial I linked to, where it is set up in `onCreate`.

Comment: Now I get ERROR/AndroidRuntime(332): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error: CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT));

Comment: @Cg2916 Thats some kind of SQL syntax error, if I were you I'd create a new question with the details.